# Gnuplot - Update graph each second

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, gnuplot

I want to draw a graph that changes each second. I use below code, it changes the graph periodically. But each iteration doesn't keep previous iteration's points. How can I do it?
There is only one points each second. But I want to draw the graph with history datas.

```
FILE *pipe = popen("gnuplot -persist", "w");

// set axis ranges
fprintf(pipe,"set xrange [0:11]\n");
fprintf(pipe,"set yrange [0:11]\n");

int b = 5;int a;
for (a=0;a<11;a++) // 10 plots
{
    fprintf(pipe,"plot '-' using 1:2 \n");  // so I want the first column to be x values, second column to be y
    // 1 datapoints per plot
    fprintf(pipe, "%d %d \n",a,b);  // passing x,y data pairs one at a time to gnuplot

    fprintf(pipe,"e \n");    // finally, e
    fflush(pipe);   // flush the pipe to update the plot
    usleep(1000000);// wait a second before updating again
}

//  close the pipe
fclose(pipe);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments:

1. The default in gnuplot is that x data are from the first column and y data are from the second. You do not need the `using 1:2` specification.
2. If you want 10 plots, the form of the `for` loop should be `for (a = 0; a < 10; a++)`.

There isn't a good way in gnuplot to add to a line that already exists, so it may make sense to store your values to be plotted in an array, and loop over that array:

```
#include <vector>

FILE *pipe = popen("gnuplot -persist", "w");

// set axis ranges
fprintf(pipe,"set xrange [0:11]\n");
fprintf(pipe,"set yrange [0:11]\n");

int b = 5;int a;

// to make 10 points
std::vector<int> x (10, 0.0); // x values
std::vector<int> y (10, 0.0); // y values

for (a=0;a<10;a++) // 10 plots
{
    x[a] = a;
    y[a] = // some function of a
    fprintf(pipe,"plot '-'\n");
    // 1 additional data point per plot
    for (int ii = 0; ii <= a; ii++) {
        fprintf(pipe, "%d %d\n", x[ii], y[ii]) // plot `a` points
    }

    fprintf(pipe,"e\n");    // finally, e
    fflush(pipe);   // flush the pipe to update the plot
    usleep(1000000);// wait a second before updating again
}

//  close the pipe
fclose(pipe);
```

Of course, you probably want to avoid hard-coding magic numbers (e.g. 10), but this is just an example.

Comment: thanks! this code is work. But this solution isn't based on gnuplot. I try to find a solution based on gnuplot commands.If I can't find it,I use this code. Thanks you very much again.